# S3 Signed Url generated as IAM User don't expire in time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I have a very odd problem that I tried to fix for days with no luck.
So I want to provide links to download s3 files to ANY person who clicks the link. I use a Node.js lambda function to generate the code. Here is the code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey,
      region: 'eu-central-1',
      signatureVersion: 's3v4'
    });

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    console.log(AWS.config);
    
    const s3Bucket = event.s3Bucket;
    const s3Key = event.s3Key;
    const downloadName = encodeURI(event.downloadName);
    const expireSeconds = event.expireSeconds;

    const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: s3Bucket,
            Key: s3Key,
            Expires: parseInt(expireSeconds),
            ResponseContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${downloadName}"`,
        });
        
    console.log("Generated downloadLink: " + url);
    return  {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify("Success"),
            downloadLink: url
        };
```

Now here is the strangeness:

- with Expires:5 the link will return  `Request has expired` after 5seconds, all good.
- with Expires:3600 (1 hour) the link will continue to work even after 3600 seconds. Only when I manually remove a char from the &X-Amz-Security-Token in the link it will return `Request has expired` after 3600s. When I remove a char before 3600s I get `InvalidToken`
- with Expires:604800 (7 days) the link will stop working after 36 hours and I get a `ExpiredToken` (explained here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/)

So it seems there is a problem with the credentials and/or AWS SDK config. I log AWS.config after updating with the IAM credentials and it shows the correct accessKeyID. The generated link however shows something else in X-Amz-Credential (not sure if it is supposed to show the IAM key).
The IAM User shows "Last Activity: Never" in the IAM dashboard (even tho the AWS.congig loggs its key?).

Does anybody have the slightest idea, how to fix or debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution just after posting...
First I made sure that const s3 = new AWS.S3() is set after the AWS.config.update (I have updated the code above).
Secondly I have to use a private tab to test the links. Otherwise they will work even if expired.

Hope this helps others on their journey.

Comment: The SDK client object `s3 = new AWS.S3()` that you created in the original version of your code inherited the credentials associated with the IAM role that the Lambda function was launched with. Those credentials have different expiration, and potentially different permissions, to your IAM user credentials. You configured a new set of (IAM user) credentials via `AWS.config.update(...)` *after* you created the client object, so it didn't have any effect on the client object. Also, the fact that the links worked on you laptop browser after expiration is related to caching.